# File is in owner's trash

Tags: google-drive

I received a link to a file on Google Drive. When I try to open it, it says "File is in owner's trash" and there is no Download button.

How can I download it?

Comment: Ask the owner to take it out the trash.

Answer (score 1):

You have to ask the file owner restore the file and to allow you to download the file.